# Userscript to show author of comment in inbox

Tags: support, userscript

First off, I know this exists, and I used it before. I just can't remember the name off the top of my head.

I want a user script that will show comments (and possibly answers), looking like this:

[Site icon] comment [User name, ex. John Smith]

What is this called, and where do I get it?

Comment: Any if these: https://stackapps.com/search?q=comment+%5Bscript%5D+inbox ?

Comment: Nope, didn't work after all, although I thought it would.

Comment: FWIW, this is one of the features of my [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091) userscript if you're still interested :) (`Add the author's name to notifications in the inbox` in the settings dialog)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Thanks. Unfortunately it's of little interest to me now, but I will keep it in mind for the future. If you add it as an answer I will accept it.